# Preventing orphans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to prevent single word orphans by adding a non breaking space between the last 2 words within paragraphs and headings. The script I am using however is having the side effect of removing links too.

```js
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function() {
    var wordArray = $(this).text().split(" ");
    var finalTitle = "";
    for (i=0;i<=wordArray.length-1;i++) {
        finalTitle += wordArray[i];
        if (i == (wordArray.length-2)) {
            finalTitle += "&nbsp;";
        } else { 
            finalTitle += " ";
        }
    }
    $(this).html(finalTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <a href="test.php">It has survived</a> not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.</p>
<p> only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software.</p>
```

Comment: Seems not ideal to do this on the front end, if avoidable. If possible, better to add `&nbsp;` on the backend before the content is rendered to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `html()` instead of `text()`:

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function(i,e) {
  var text = $(e).html();
  text = text.split(' ');
  var lastWord = text.pop();
  text = text.join(' ') + "&nbsp;" + lastWord;
  $(e).html(text);
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/owk2dzbe/)

Btw, there is one corner case it doesn't work for, and it's when last single word of element to be unorphaned is inside the `<a>`, or any other tag with attributes, like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="">amet.</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks that diid the job. I am happy for links to be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `.text()` which gets the combined text of the element and it's decedents, not the decedent elements themselves, so when you replace the HTML with something generated from this, it doesn't include them.

You might have better luck using `.contents()`, taking the last `text` node, and replacing that with a `text` node, an `&nbsp;` element and a `text` node representing the final word.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function noMoreLonelyWords(selector, numWords){

      // Get array of all the selected elements
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i){

        // Split the text content of each element into an array
        var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");

        // Remove the last n words and join them with a none breaking space
        var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");

        // Join it all back together and replace the existing
        // text with the new text
        var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
        elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " +  lastWords;
      }
    }

    // Goodbye lonely words
    noMoreLonelyWords("p", 2);
```

```html
<div class="onePar">
  <p>This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say
    something like this:
  </p>
</div>

<div class="twoPar">
  <p>This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say
    something like this:
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this strips out line breaks