# Preventing orphaned words but exclude <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122565/preventing-orphans#answer-41123107) to prevent orphaned words by inserting `&nbsp;` between the last two word within paragraphs and headings.

As the author states, it doesn't work when the last word is inside the `<a>` tag.

So

```
<p>Call us at <a href="tel:+18001234567">1-800-123-4567</a></p>
```

renders as

```
<p>Call us at <a&nbsp;href="tel:+18001234567">1-800-123-4567</a&nbsp;href="tel:+18001234567"></p>
```

Can this be fixed so that it ignores any content inside html tags?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question is quite naive in the way it goes about finding words. It will break on any inline elements with attributes. The other problem you'll have is that the hyphens in your phone number are natural word wrap breaks, so your number will orphan itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552371/1772933) and adapted to rebuilding your html. Note that regex gets a little iffy-er the more complex and nested your html. However, works like a charm here! The post link explains the regex in detail.

```js
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function() {
  result = $(this).html().match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
  let out = "";
  result.forEach(function(seg, index){
    let sep;
    if (index == result.length - 1) sep = "";
    else if (index == result.length - 2) sep = "&nbsp;";
    else sep = " ";
    out += seg + sep;
  })
  $(this).html(out);
  console.log($(this).prop('outerHTML'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Call us at <a href="tel:+18001234567">1-800-123-4567</a></p>
```

In case it helps troubleshooting the gulp issue, here is a minified version

```
$("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").each(function(){result=$(this).html().match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);let t="";result.forEach(function(h,s){let l;l=s==result.length-1?"":s==result.length-2?"&nbsp;":" ",t+=h+l}),$(this).html(t),console.log($(this).prop("outerHTML"))});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm having trouble compiling your code. I'm using the latest version of WordPress with jQuery v3.5.1.

Comment: Nothing in the console and nothing specific but "gulp-notify: [Gulp - Error] Error: unable to minify JavaScript"

Comment: I think that's because this is es6 format (bc it uses the arrow function). You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521506/gulpuglifyerrorunable-to-minify-javascript/52433197 but the es6 isn't important here. I updated my answer for es5

Comment: The updated code did not work and I haven't updated my gulp file because it's used company wide and can't be modified for one script. Is it possible to update the script without using es?

Comment: @Junky - all javascript is es, but apparently older versions of gulp uglify choke on es6 (which the orig answer was, but the revised answer (es5) isn't). I posted a minified version if that helps. Otherwise, the question was answered and solved and the gulp issue is probably a new question. I hope my work helped.

Comment: I'll have to fix the gulp issue some other time but will accept the answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need more rep to comment on Kinglish' answer, but to avoid having a space between the link and a period, add in:

```
else if (result.slice(-1) == "." && index == result.length-2) sep = "";
```

This checks if the last character of a string matches a period, and if so injects nothing rather than  .

The code I ended up using is as follows:

```
jQuery("p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, blockquote, .ct-text-block").each(function() {
    result = jQuery(this).html().match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
    let out = "";
    result.forEach(function(seg, index){
    let sep;
    if (index == result.length-1) sep = "";
        else if (result.slice(-1) == "." && index == result.length-2) sep = "";
        else if (result.slice(-1) == "!" && index == result.length-2) sep = "";
        else if (result.slice(-1) == "?" && index == result.length-2) sep = "";
        else if (index == result.length-2) sep = "&nbsp;";
        else sep = " ";
        out += seg + sep;
    })
jQuery(this).html(out);
});
```

I looked around to see if I could find a more streamlined way to check against several special characters, I might report back if I find a simpler solution.